# Login to yammer through axapta

Tags: authentication, axapta, yammer

I have an assignment to develop a functionality for the Microsoft Dynamics AX (2012) i.e. in the SalesTable form I need to open a browser with automatically authentication to Yammer.
By analyzing the http webRequests (with Fiddler tool ) I have discovered that for this purpose there several web request are sending (with specific parameters and cookies) in certain sequence, such as:

```
1. https://www.yammer.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=VALUE&redirect_uri=https://www.yammer.com

2. https://www.yammer.com/dialog/authenticate?client_id=VALUE

3. https://www.yammer.com/images/public-site-spacer.gif

4. https://persona.yammer.com/login_provider.json?email=VALUE&state=VALUE

5. https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=VALUE&domain_hint=VALUE&login_hint=&nonce=2VALUE&redirect_uri=VALUE&response_mode=query&response_type=id_token&scope=open_id&site_id=VALUE&state=VALUE

6. https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/userrealm/?user=VALUE&api-version=VALUE&stsRequest=VALUE&checkForMicrosoftAccount=VALUE
7. https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/login
```

All these request I sending programmatically and can catch the web Response object from such web request, except request #7. With Fiddler tool I can see than additional request has been send automatically to the:

```
1. https://persona.yammer.com/office_sessions?id_token=VALUE&state=&session_state=VALUE
```

and to the URI above just after #8

```
2. https://www.yammer.com/?persona_token=VALUE&state=
```

When I try to create requests #8 and #9 programmatically (let’s say #8My and #9My) I have an error.
My final goal is to get some mandatory parameters such as: ("browser_token", "oauth_token" and "code") from the webResponses on the #8 and #9 requests.
Can you please help me to define how to get them? Maybe I should skip some request listed above or add some additional requests (which one?)?
Thank you

Commented as of 16.06.2016
I will try to localize the problem (because there are quite a lot of gaps and for the sake of clarity I will ask questions one by one), thank you for understanding.
Below there is a screenshot of my requests
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrY8w.jpg)
On the step #7 I’m sending the following request: 
GET https://persona.yammer.com/login_provider.json?email=myEmail@myDomain.com&state=41a563bc24e263ed5b35fbe63e7c5c556a0477024d88b28fb012ed6de48b1d39 HTTP/1.1
Host: persona.yammer.com
Cookie: yamtrak_id=2b9ea0d1-55c4-4368-b893-d9b7e3b1da32

Fiddler shows me, that in response of this request (#7), there is parameter “_session_id=” (value is showed below and in red rectangular on the screenshot)
_session_id=Zlk2YjlkcFZPdTZlOHAwVHl4L0lodC85K1VvaUFkbWxNZU5LZzNLcWR6SU1JWEI4c0l1aFpjMmhGNlllcEFVQ1VtNVN6R1lwTGxoZFNIYW5zb3pKSlE9PS0tdWxIVXEzR3JIN0RQcUsvU2svOVY4QT09--6fc208ae3d6d939e3e2e7eecfffd1d23d3051f39;
This parameter (_session_id) will be used in request #12.
But when I grab (programmatically) the cookies in response of the request #7, the value of this parameter is absolutely different from mentioned above (and the name of the parameter is “_session=” (instead of “_session_id=”). 
_session=BAh7CUkiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFRkkiJTU0OGYyOTQ0YTAxNzYyNjUzZmJlMGI2ZmZjOTU3ZWI4BjsAVEkiC21vYmlsZQY7AEZGSSIQX2NzcmZfdG9rZW4GOwBGSSIxTlZRZkFJRTZHeHdJWUtxcUtVNHEzWXNKeDZ2Z2FiQUZ6NXJIalM0Nk0zTT0GOwBGSSIKZmxhc2gGOwBGbzolQWN0aW9uRGlzcGF0Y2g6OkZsYXNoOjpGbGFzaEhhc2gJOgxAY2xvc2VkRjoNQGZsYXNoZXN7CToKZXJyb3IwOgl0cmZlMDoLbm90aWNlMDoJdHJmbjA6CUBub3cwOgpAdXNlZG86CFNldAY6CkBoYXNoewk7CVQ7ClQ7C1Q7DFQ%3D--ea5007eba2efabc2627f2e5af66c4c57f22d53bb
Here is the code of how I’m getting the Cookies string from the HttpWebResponse

```
public string getStringCookies(System.Net.HttpWebResponse _response)
        {
            string cookies = string.Empty;

            try
            {

                cookies = _response.Headers["Set-Cookie"];
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error in SetCookies: " + ex.Message);
            }
            return cookies;
        }
```

So the question is: what should I do in order to catch the _session_id parameter in the response of the request #7?

Comment: You say you get an error, yet there is no error message in your question? What is the error you're getting?

Comment: I added some explanation to the initial question (with screenshot attachment) dated (Commented as of 16.06.2016)